# Why do all the Checkbox's in my Outline View check when only one is clicked?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am using a Outline view with two columns one a text field the other a check box field. Each column is binded to a NSTreeController. The problem I have is that when I click on a Checkbox I only want it to check that one check box but it checks all of them in the column. To help answer my Question this is the Bindings : http://snapplr.com/x5yh  and this is the entity model: http://snapplr.com/vqc9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The controller key is wrong. Use `arrangedObjects` instead of `selection`.

`selection` will display the value of the current selected object.